# Property accessed during render but not defined in VUE

Tags: vue.js

I receive an error when I load the page

[image]

My code looks like this **:**

```
 <script>
    methods: {
      getPicture() {
        var base = this;         
      axios
          .get("http://localhost:3000/pictures/" + this.username)
          .then(function (response) {
           const { pictureData } = response.data;
           base.studentImage = "data:image/jpg; base64," + pictureData;

           console.log(base.studentImage);
       });
     },
     }, //END OF METHOD
 </script>
```

I want to display image in My front end. Where do I make a mistake ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: There should be a `data` item defined as `studentImage` in your script. Can you please share the full script part of your component?

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 0):

**Welcome to Stack Overflow!**

*Sadly, I can't comment on this for more clarity, so my response has to be an answer.*

This error occurs because the DOM and/or Vue Instance and/or Template uses the value "studentImage" before it is made available or defined incorrectly.

I recommend removing the variable "base" because Vue is very picky with its use of "this," so you usually wanna stay away from explicitly assigning "this" to a variable. As commented by Estus Flask below, this even applies to common JS. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback) for more information on referring to the correct "this" in JS.

Honestly, from what I can see with the code you've shared, that's likely the cause of your error. You'll want to define "studentImage" within your data object so Vue is aware of its existence.

**Here is an example:**

```js
data: () => ({
  studentImage: '',
}),
methods: {
      getPicture() {        
      axios
          .get("http://localhost:3000/pictures/" + this.username)
          .then(function (response) {
           const { pictureData } = response.data;
           this.studentImage = "data:image/jpg; base64," + pictureData;

           console.log(this.studentImage);
       });
     },
  },
```

If it is not, then you'll want to make sure you're checking for "studentImage" before using it within the instance and or calling the method "getPicture," in the appropriate [lifecycle](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html#lifecycle-diagram).

I'm answering this assuming you're using the latest version of Vue, version three.

If this helps, please let me know!

Comment: this result is this "MainLayout.vue?713b:311 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'studentImage')"

Comment: in my template tag i have this   <img :src="studentImage" />

Comment: "I recommend removing the variable "base" because Vue is very picky with its use of "this," - it's not about Vue, this is common JS thing, and it was solved the wrong way in the post. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback

Comment: @QuasarDev – can you please share your entire template code?